Ethical guidelines for using uncensored photos of individuals in global health presentations
I have attended numerous global health meetings and conferences where I've observed scientists sharing uncensored photos of individuals, often from Africa and Asia, in their presentation slides. These photos frequently depict people, including children and infants, living in poorer conditions. In many cases, the individuals in the photos have been associated with specific health conditions, such as diseases or nutritional deficiencies.
I find this practice deeply disturbing and unethical, especially considering that I have never witnessed the use of similar uncensored photos of individuals from Western countries in such presentations.
Are there any established guidelines, consensus, or best practices regarding the use of identifiable images of individuals, particularly those from disadvantaged regions, in global health presentations? I would greatly appreciate guidance from the wider community to help articulate my concerns and address this issue effectively.

Did the authors create these photos? If they are using photos from journalists, there ethics are considerably different.

They have been mixed. I have seen presentations where they provide credit to the photographer. Not sure if they are journalists or someone on the scientist's team.

Does public health have "participants"? The privacy concerns surround identifying individuals who were part of a study; but if public health is working only with institutional data, then there is no risk of identifying someone personally (although I get why this can give you the ick).
